# How to print current date and date -7 days

Tags: karate

How to print current date and date -7 days

How to print current date and date -7 days
* def getDate = function(7){def date = new Date();date.setDate(date.getDate() - (7));return date.toString()}
* print getDate

Comment: please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
* def currentDate = Java.type('java.time.LocalDate').now().format(Java.type('java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter').ofPattern('yyyy-MM-dd'))
* def pastDate = Java.type('java.time.LocalDate').now().minusDays(7).format(Java.type('java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter').ofPattern('yyyy-MM-dd'))
* print('Current Date: ' + currentDate)
* print('Date -7 Days: ' + pastDate)
```